# Conditional Probability in Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Ms. A is taking driving test to get her driving license. 
The probability of passing a test is 0.3 which remains same no matter how many times she takes the test. 
Let $X$ is a random variable which is the number of tests she takes to get her license.

1) Use conditional probability rule to determine her chance of getting the license on the 6th test starting from her first attempt considering it is known that she has already failed on the first 4 tests.

2) Though one can take the driving test 6 times within a six-month period, he/she can take tests until getting licensed. How many tests is Ms. A expected to take to get the license? What is the standard deviation of the number of tests she takes to get licensed?

For 1), should I take $P(4 < X \le 6)$?

For 2) logically speaking, if she tries 3 times, $0.3\cdot3 = 0.9$, but if she tries 4 times, $0.3\cdot4 = 1.2$ means that after 4 times is supposed to pass the test. Am I correct? 
As for the standard deviation, $V(X) = (1-p)/p^2 = 0.7/0.3^2 = 7.77$, correct?

Comment: 1) Let $A$ be the event she gets licensed on th sixth trial, and $B$ the event she has failed $4$ times. You want $\Pr(A|B)$ and the conditional probability rule may be $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$.  But you can also get the answer immediately from the memorylesssness of the geometric distribution.   2) My guess is that you have been given formulas for the mean and variance of a geometric random variable, and you are just expected to plug in.

Answer (score 1):

> For 1), should I take $P(4<X≤6)$?

No.  That is the probability of passing on *either* the fifth or sixth try (and it's not conditioned).

You want to find the *conditional* probability of passing on the sixth trial when it is given that the first four were failures.

That is: $P(X = 6\mid X\geq 4)$

Use the definition of **Conditional Probability**, and the *memoryless* property of the **Geometric Distribution**.

> For 2) logically speaking, if she tries 3 times, $0.3\cdot 3=0.9$, but if she tries 4 times, $0.3\cdot 4=1.2$ means that after 4 times is supposed to pass the test. Am I correct?

Not in the slightest.   You use the probability of failure, and they combine multiplicatively rather than additively (ie use an exponent not a coefficient).   The probability of requiring $k$ or more tries to pass is: the probability of failing the first $k-1$ tries. $$\mathsf P(X\geq k) = 0.7^{k-1}$$

However *what you need to do* is to use the properties of Geometric Distribution: $$\mathsf E(X) = \tfrac 1 p = \frac 1{0.3} = \frac{10}{3} \\ \mathsf{Var}(X) = \tfrac{1-p}{p^2} = \frac{1-0.3}{0.3^2} = \frac {70} 9$$

And combine these with memorylessness to obtain:$\mathsf E(X\mid X\geq 4), \mathsf{Var}(X\mid X\geq 4)$

---

Hint: $\mathsf E(X+a)= \mathsf E(X)+a, \mathsf{Var}(X+a) = \mathsf {Var}(X)$